# Spin-Boson coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

Typically while coupling a single spin to a bunch of bosons (Harmonic oscillators) a $\sigma_x$ or $\sigma_z$ coupling operator is chosen for the system operator coupled to the position of the bosons, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
H=\frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_z + \frac{\Omega}{2}\sigma_x +\sum_k \frac{p_k^2}{2m_k}+\frac{m_k\omega_k^2}{2}x_k^2 + S\otimes\sum_k c_kx_k
\end{equation}
with $S = \sigma_x$ or $\sigma_z$. Why is a more general operator not considered? e.g. $S=\begin{pmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12} \\
s_{21} & s_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$ or $S = \sigma_x + \sigma_z$. Is there a fundamental experimental problem in realizing such a coupling? If someone does know of such general operators being considered I would love to see the reference.

Answer (score 1):

The examples you consider "more general operator(s)" are just the ordinary Pauli matrices rotated, thus are in fact not more general (the spin system part will change correspondingly though). Further however there are other cases considered for instance higher spins (LMG model coupled to bosonic bath).

As for your last question, this Hamiltonian describes for instance a two state atom interacting with photons. So for instance one can use it to see how an excited electron would decay (decohere) to its ground state. So it models a very simple process.